# getBalance of shows the wrong balance

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I have this code to show the erc20 token balance of an account

```
   var tokenAddress = '0xb97E9bBB6fd49865709d3F1576e8506ad640a13B';
var walletAddress = '0x62f28320f688A7A4e0021c55d7ffD1acd770A133';



    function getERC20TokenBalance() {

      let minABI = [
        // balanceOf
        {
          "constant":true,
          "inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],
          "name":"balanceOf",
          "outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],
          "type":"function"
        },
        // decimals
        {
          "constant":true,
          "inputs":[],
          "name":"decimals",
          "outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],
          "type":"function"
        }
      ];


      let contract2 = web3.eth.contract(minABI).at(tokenAddress);

      web3.eth.getAccounts(function (error, walletAddress) {
          contract2.balanceOf(walletAddress, function(err, result) {
              if(err) {
                  console.log(err, 'err');
              } else {
                console.log(result);
                  document.getElementById('agiAvailable').innerHTML = result + ' AGI';

              }
          });
      });
    }
    getERC20TokenBalance();

    function onAddressChange(e) {

      if(tokenAddress != "" && walletAddress != "") {
        getERC20TokenBalance(tokenAddress, walletAddress, (balance) => {
          console.log(balance.toString());
        });
      }
    }
```

But that output is 0, which is not the correct balance

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this will answer your question:

`walletAddress = '0x62f28320f688A7A4e0021c55d7ffD1acd770A133'` → `walletAddress[0] = '0'`.

And when you call `contract2.balanceOf(walletAddress[0])`, web3 most likely converts that `'0'` into the zero address `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'`, whose balance is apparently 0.

**Side note:**

You're obviously using web3.js v0.x here; I think that web3.js v1.x would possibly throw an "invalid value for `address` type" exception on this, so it might be worth upgrading your web3.js version.

Comment: but this wasnt the issue, even with removing the [0], its still not working.

Comment: @CodingJoe: This is **definitely** an issue. There could be more than one issue of course. Please fix it to begin with, then indicate what error you're getting.

Comment: @CodingJoe: And BTW, fix up your code first. Why are you calling `getERC20TokenBalance()` "out of nowhere", without doing anything with its return value, and without passing any input parameters to it??? Why are you not doing anything with the `callback` parameter which you are passing to it??? How do you expect this function to execute that `callback` which you are passing??? Code must be well organized. Don't just "throw stuff into it" hoping something would eventually work.

Comment: i updated the code- i dont get any error but the output is still not correct- it says =0

Comment: @CodingJoe: Please read the comment above.

Comment: ok, i removed the callback functions and that stuff inside the getERC20TokenBalance and it now works. Dude i dont know why i did that, i copied the code from here because they are talking about what i try to do? view-source:https://piyolab.github.io/playground/ethereum/getERC20TokenBalance/

Comment: @CodingJoe: Do you know basic programming in Javascript? If you remove the `callback` parameter, then the part `(balance) => {console.log(balance.toString());});` will not be invoked!!! And again,what exactly is the meaning of `getERC20TokenBalance();`??? You are calling this function without passing to it any of the input parameters that it expects!!!

Comment: I have updated the code to a code that works for me. I tried with these parameters and callback but i would get no output, by removing it it works. and with getERC20Tokenbalance i start the function- if i dont do that i get no output

Comment: i use this with every function or it wouldnt work
https://pastebin.com/8au4up4k

Comment: how can i make this better? and how can i access the variables like sellPrice buy Price balanceof my Dividends etc.  i always get a undefined

Comment: i read up on here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp about functions but i cant declare my fucntion and the output in a varibale